# Compiling C program using mysql under WSL

Tags: c, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clion, mysql-connector

I'm newbie with WSL and there is a lot of time spent from my last C compilation.
I have a small C program which compile and execute with WSL (in the CLion dev environment, which use CMake to compile and link)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char server[16] = "localhost"; char username[16] = "root";
   char password[16] = ""; char database[16] = "sports";

   char *conn = NULL;
   if (conn == NULL) {
      printf("MySQL: initialisation de %s a echouee", database);
      return 1;
   }
}
```

then i'm trying to add some database functionalities; a minimal one is connecting to the database

```
#include "include/mysql.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char server[16] = "localhost"; char username[16] = "root";
   char password[16] = ""; char database[16] = "sports";

   MYSQL* conn = mysql_init(NULL);
   if (conn == NULL) {
      printf("MySQL: initialisation de %s a echouee", database);
      return 1;
   }
}
```

Here, I need to get the mysql environment and to link to the lib. My reference is:
[Link to the MYSQL C Api doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/5.7/en/c-api-implementations.html)
My understanding is that I need to link my code with libmysqlclient.a. But, I'm not able to find the library. I've done:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

But then, I'm not able to find the mysql library and and include(s) file(s) and to understand how to link it. I've tried:

```
find_package(MYSQL REQUIRED)
```

in the Cmake file, but without success.
Any helps, advices, pointers are welcome.

Comment: "My understanding is that I need to link my code with libmysqlclient.a. But, I'm not able to find the library." - Searching for the Ubuntu package with a library is not so difficult: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libmysqlclient. It founds [libmysqlclient-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libmysqlclient-dev).

Comment: Thank's. But, it is just a step. So, I also done sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev (which works) and then? where is the library? where are the include files? why the find_package cmake command doesn't find the mysql package and how to go forward. I'm reading pages and pages of documentation and I'm still stuck

Comment: I think there  are in /usr/include/mysql and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. So, I can perhaps avoid to expect an answer from the find_package command. Then, I will try to specify directly the link in my cmake file

Comment: There is no ready-made support for `find_package(MySQL)`, neither in CMake itself (it doesn't provide script `FindMySQL.cmake`), nor in MySQL package (it doesn't provide script `MySQLConfig.cmake`). However, it is not so difficult to write script `FindMySQL.cmake` and ship it with your project. See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157432/where-is-findmysql-cmake-in-recent-linux-distributions) for more info.