# MySQL Connector/C++ on CLion giving error while including xdevapi.h

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake, clion, mysql-connector

In Windows 10.I inluded MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include file to my project after that i included boost file to my project.

I included "include" and "boost" file at CMakefile also here's cmakefile :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(SQLTitTacTeo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "C:/Users/sefak/Desktop/FindSQL")
find_package(MySQL REQUIRED)

add_executable(SQLTitTacTeo main.cpp SQL.cpp SQL.h)
```

It give me error :

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2019.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\sefak\Desktop\KodumunYeri\SQLTitTacTeo
CMake Error at C:/Users/sefak/Desktop/FindSQL/FindMySQL.cmake:112 (MESSAGE):
Cannot find MySQL.  Include dir: C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server
8.0/include library dir:
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/sefak/Desktop/KodumunYeri/SQLTitTacTeo/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/sefak/Desktop/KodumunYeri/SQLTitTacTeo/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

[Finished]
```

I downloaded MySQL WorkBench 8.0 CE from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/). And here is the MySQL file [image]

I  tried :

1. Another versions of connector/c++ library
2. Another versions of boost
3. Some changes at CMake
4. Tried adding find_package(MySQL REQUIRED) to cmakelist but it says
   can't find package
5. Tried [this](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/master/CMake/FindMySQL.cmake) CMakeList it doesn't gived any error but nothing happened still geting no such file error while trying to use "xdevapi.h"
6. Tried changing CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH but it gives same error (does not recognised)
7. Tried using set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake") it gives same by not providing "FindMySQL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH error
8. Tried to add include_directories(C:/Program Files/MySQL) and 
   link_libraries(C:/Program Files/MySQL) but nothing happened
9. Tried adding include_directories(${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR}) to cmake

Comment: "Undefined reference" error is resolved by **linking** with a library, but your code doesn't link anything. See the duplicate question for a way for link with mysql library in CMake project.

Comment: I do not know how to use CMake properly. I take multiple errors when i tried [this](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/master/CMake/FindMySQL.cmake) also i tried linking manually then it gives me cannot find library error.In short i tried like everything i found in everywhere but everytime i got another error.I don't know what to do atm

Comment: " i tried like everything i found in everywhere but everytime i got another error" - Please, show (add to the question post) what **exactly** have you **tried** and what errors you got on these attempts. Otherwise we simply cannot help you.

Comment: Well, linking is definitely required and `mysqlCon/lib64` is definitely wrong file to link (there is no such file actually). Way with `find_package(MySQL)` should work, and `FindMySQL.cmake` script you refer in the (5) possibly working. Please, describe this way in **more details**: What **exact code** (`CMakeLists.txt`) you use with this way? What **exact error message** you got? Where/How have you installed MySQL or MySQL connector on your system?

Comment: I downloaded MySQL from it's offical site Connector c++ 8.0 comes with it. I copied include and lib64 folder from downloaded file it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSsYv.png). And i copied it to my project.

Comment: So it is Windows after all. Please, [edit] the question and add into it this information and the other information requested in my previous comment.

Comment: Ok, you use `find_package(MySQL)`. But what about **other lines** from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35069320/3440745) to the duplicate question? Where do you use `MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR` for include directories? Where do you use `MYSQL_LIB` for link with it? And once more: The script you found is named `FindMySQL.cmake`. It is NOT `CMakeLists.txt` and is NOT intended to be copy pasted into your `CMakeLists.txt`. This script is intended to be **copied** (as a **file**, preserving its name) into your project and used via `find_package(MySQL)`. See my answer for more details.

Comment: I updated my problem with it. Thanks for helping btw. If i make you angry at any point sorry about that i realy am bad about CMakeList. But i'm trying my best